# Is it possible to use the preview video stream for a separate use?

Tags: android, video, webrtc, preview

I'm trying to figure out how I can take advantage of the (low res) preview when recording high res video.

The ideal intention is to stream the low quality video via WebRTC to the internet, but I'm unclear on how (or even if) this is possible.

There is a callback from the preview that hands me preview frames. In a worse case scenario I can send those as individual picture frames. This is obviously not the most efficient way to do it.

Curious if anyone has some boilerplate I can repurpose for piping the preview out to any sort of bytestream that I can decode as video on the receiving end of a WebSocket, but would much prefer the WebRTC solution if someone has a line on that.

Comment: have a look at https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming

Comment: @AlexCohn, thanks... that looks promising but just glancing at the code, I get the sense that it's turning the bytestream of the HD video (and not the preview video) that it uses. Am I overlooking a way to use the preview stream instead?

Comment: If I understand correctly, there is only one "stream" that comes from the camera. Unlike onPreviewFrame/onPictureTaken, the video recorder uses the same resolution as preview stream, even if this goes through hardware accelerated channel: this all depends on the sensor configuration. You can choose lower frame rate for the video you send, you can tune the encoder bitrate, or even subsample the frames to reduce resolution.